# URL without parameters but PHP gets Parameter (.htaccess?)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

(Sorry for my bad english. I’m from Germany)

I'm trying to get nice URLs for an Imageviewer.

I just got the htaccess-Code for the Subdomain

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} i.domain.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/imageviewer
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /imageviewer/$1 [L]
```

Thats the result I wish to see. If I navigate to i.domain.de the browser shows the right URL and the index.php from /imageviewer/ is shown.

But I want nice URLs. Now I have URLs with Parameters like **i.domain.de/?id=2ntxfi** or **i.domain.de/index.php?id=2ntxfi**
But I want it to be **i.domain.de/2ntxfi/**
PHP should still get the $_GET['id'] Parameter.

How can I achieve this?

*Sidenote: I have a vServer. So I can install Apache extensions if this should be required.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `/imageviewer/.htaccess` and have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /imageviewer/

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```